# MySQL filters query

Tags: mysql, search, select, filter

I got table of links between goods and filters, like this:
id, good_id, filter_id.

When user notes checkboxes i have to show him all goods, that got link with all of those filters.

My vision of the query is: 
(if user checked filters: 1,2 and 3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t0.gid) 
FROM links as t0, links as t1, links as t2 
WHERE t0.filter_id=1 AND 
      t1.good_id=t0.good_id AND t1.filter_id=2 AND 
      t2.good_id=t1.good_id AND t2.filter_id=3
```

But in this way, we'll got a trouble, if there are a lot of checked filters..

So, how would you solve the task?

Comment: Which kind of trouble are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Are you trying to select goods linked to *all* of `1, 2, 3` or to *any* of `1, 2, 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need GID's which have at least one of filters

```
SELECT DISTINCT `gid` FROM `links` WHERE `filter_id` IN (1,2,3)
```

If you need GID's which have ALL filters 1,2,3

```
SELECT `gid` FROM `links` WHERE `filter_id` IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY `gid` HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT `filter_id`)=3
```

where `COUNT( DISTINCT`filter_id`)=3` means that all 3 filters are on.

Comment: Your query selecting all gids that have filters=(1 OR 2 OR 3), but not that goods, that have all these filters.

Comment: @Nikolay  Look at the second query.

Comment: My mistake. I got one more link in my table (to category). So one good can be linked twice or more times to each filter.

Comment: @Nikolay I've altered the second query (added `COUNT( DISTINCT `filter_id`)`) now it have to work. It seems that your table has doubled rows with the same (gid,filter_id) pairs.

Comment: thank you! It's very nice, when somebody helps you just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  gid
FROM    links
WHERE   filter_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
        gid
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT filter_id) = 3
```